# How to express a fraction into product of two terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to express the following fraction:
$$x^2\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right)^2+x\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right) + 1$$ into

$$K(y-c)(y-d),$$ where $c$ and $d$ are zeroes of the above function. How can I do this decomposition?

The above function is a function of both $x$ and $y$, and $K$ is also a function of both $x$ and $y$. $c$ and $d$ are only function of $x$.

Comment: What is $K$? Is it a function of $x$?

Comment: Take $\left(\dfrac{y-1}{y+1}\right)=A$. That'll make the expression as,

$$(Ax)^2+(Ax)+1$$
 
which is a quadratic in terms of $Ax$. Maybe this might help?

Comment: Multiply through by $(y+1)^2$...

Answer (score 1):

Such a decomposition is not possible.

Your first expression is undefined for $y=-1$ whereas your desired form $K(y-c)(y-d)$ is defined for all $y$. Therefore the two expressions cannot be equivalent. Of course, if you limit $x$ in some ways, such as $x=0$, your first expression does have a *limit* as $y$ approaches $-1$. But that is not the same thing and would only work for those special values of $x$.

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra implies that any *polynomial* with complex coefficients can be written as a constant times the product of linear polynomials. But this applies to polynomials, whereas your expression is a *rational* expression of $y$, quite a different thing.

Comment: It may be possible if $K$ is a function of $\frac{1}{y+1}$ or $(\frac{1}{y+1})^2$.

Comment: Yes. That would be equivalent to @abiessu's comment "Multiply through by $(y+1)^2$".